# How to use "Introduce variation based on..." in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 8.0 introduce variation based usage

[image]

Comment: (Make that _"introduce variation based on …"_, at the very least.) What are you trying to achieve, what have you tried that didn't work, what _specific_ question could Stack Overflow help you with? See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It looks fairly self explanatory to me.

The options for "based on" seem to be different size classes (and gamut now with the iPhone 7 wide colour gamut).

This will add another `Background color` (in this case) to the inspector that will allow you to select a different option based on the size class/gamut configuration you have selected.